# Can I print function type in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I want to print the type of a function.

```
func thanksTo(name: String) {
    print("Thanks, \(name)")
}

printType(thanksTo)    // expected to print "Function (String) -> ()"
```

Is there any function in Swift that behaves like `printType`?

Comment: `printType` is a Python thing? or is it used in other languages?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Swift 3 and later

As of Swift 3, `__FUNCTION__` is deprecated. Instead, use `#function` in place of `__FUNCTION__`.

(Thank you, @jovit.royeca.)

---

### Swift 2.2 and earlier

You have a few options:

1. `print(__FUNCTION__)` will output `functionName()` if the function has no arguments.
2. `print(__FUNCTION__)` will output `functionName` (without parentheses) if the function has one or more arguments.
3. `print(functionName.dynamicType)` will output `(() -> Swift.Int) -> Swift.Int` for this hypothetical function:

   ```
   func functionName(closure: () -> Int) -> Int {

   }
   ```

Thus, to implement the desired functionality for your `printType` function, you could use a combination of Option 2 and Option 3.

Comment: Xcode 7.3 says: `__FUNCTION__` is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3, please use `#function`

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 has an interesting new print which prints the type of anything you feed it. It basically prints the same info that is contained in the Code Completion.

```
print(type(of: functionName())) // prints the return type of a function
// Array<Float>
```

Here is a convolution method from the Accelerate framework with some properties.

```
vDSP_conv(newXin, 1, kernel.reversed(), 1, &res, 1, vDSP_Length(T), vDSP_Length(N))

print(type(of: vDSP_conv)) // prints the method arguments.
// ((UnsafePointer<Float>, Int, UnsafePointer<Float>, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, Int, UInt, UInt)) -> ()

print(type(of: kernel)) // prints the property type.
// Array<Float>

print(type(of: kernel.reversed())) // prints the property type and method type from the Swift Standard Library.
// ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Array<Float>>
```

Cool stuff!

Answer (score 4):

It's now print(#function) in Xcode 7.3.1

Refer to the release notes for swift at the below location.

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

The change happened in Swift 2.2

[image]

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
println(thanksTo.dynamicType)
```